# How to change the column name in one step while executing the function?

Tags: r

I have this function called `newBamAD` which gives the following `output` (see below)when I run this function to my input dataframe, `mydf`. I want to store the result of `newBamAD(mydf)` by changing the column name bam.AD to new column name. For example, I want to change the column name `bam.AD` to new name in the same step when I run the function with my dataframe like this, `output<-newBamAD(mydf)`.

```
  output
       start           REF ALT bam.AD  
    1  "chr20:5363934" "C" "T" "59,29" 
    2  "chr5:8529759"  "G" "C" "28,41" 
    3  "chr14:9620689" "T" "G" "49,41"
```

I want like this

```
output


               start           REF ALT newname.AD  
            1  "chr20:5363934" "C" "T" "59,29" 
            2  "chr5:8529759"  "G" "C" "28,41" 
            3  "chr14:9620689" "T" "G" "49,41"
```

Comment: `?names`, `?setNames`, `help("names<-")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important whether you have a matrix or a data.frame. Matrices use the `dimnames` attribute to store row and column names, while data.frames use the `names` and `row.names` attributes to store column and row names, respectively.

From your question, it looks like you've got a matrix there in `output`, since data.frames normally don't quote character elements (regardless whether they are actually factors or true character vectors) when printing, while matrices do.

Thus, to change the column names, you have to use the [`colnames<-()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html) function. (You could alternatively use the [`dimnames<-()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dimnames.html) function, but that would require a list RHS with two components, one for row names and one for column names, and since you don't want to mess with row names, that's not helpful.)

If you want to do this in the same line as the function call, you'll have to call `colnames<-()` using backticks to protect the `<-` token from the parser. Thus we have:

```
mydf <- data.frame(); ## dummy
newBamAD <- function(mydf) matrix(c('chr20:5363934','chr5:8529759','chr14:9620689','C','G','T','T','C','G','59,29','28,41','49,41'),3,dimnames=list(1:3,c('start','REF','ALT','bam.AD')));
newBamAD(mydf);
##   start           REF ALT bam.AD
## 1 "chr20:5363934" "C" "T" "59,29"
## 2 "chr5:8529759"  "G" "C" "28,41"
## 3 "chr14:9620689" "T" "G" "49,41"
`colnames<-`(newBamAD(mydf),c('start','REF','ALT','newname.AD'));
##   start           REF ALT newname.AD
## 1 "chr20:5363934" "C" "T" "59,29"
## 2 "chr5:8529759"  "G" "C" "28,41"
## 3 "chr14:9620689" "T" "G" "49,41"
```

This has an obvious disadvantage that you have to specify names for *all* columns, rather than just the one you want to replace, but I don't see any way around that, if you want to do this inline. You could of course index the column of interest first, but then you'd lose the remaining columns, so that wouldn't work.

Of course there's nothing stopping you from capturing the return value in a variable and then selectively replacing the column name in a separate statement via index-assignment, which can be done on the same line using a semicolon:

```
output <- newBamAD(mydf); colnames(output)[colnames(output)=='bam.AD'] <- 'newname.AD';
output;
##   start           REF ALT newname.AD
## 1 "chr20:5363934" "C" "T" "59,29"
## 2 "chr5:8529759"  "G" "C" "28,41"
## 3 "chr14:9620689" "T" "G" "49,41"
```

---

Alternatively, you could return the result as a data.frame rather than a matrix, or coerce to data.frame via [`as.data.frame()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.data.frame.html), in which case you could use [`setNames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html) or [`names<-()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html), which would have identical considerations to the `colnames<-()` solution described above.

If you're willing to go the data.frame route, another possibility opens up. This is to use [`transform()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/transform.html) (or [`within()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/with.html), but `transform()` is more concise for our purposes). And actually, from testing, you can apply this function directly on a matrix, and it automatically coerces to data.frame, which is convenient. Thus we have:

```
transform(newBamAD(mydf),newname.AD=bam.AD,bam.AD=NULL);
##           start REF ALT newname.AD
## 1 chr20:5363934   C   T      59,29
## 2  chr5:8529759   G   C      28,41
## 3 chr14:9620689   T   G      49,41
```

A disadvantage of this approach is that the column data will have to be copied, whereas with the previous solutions only the naming attribute has to be touched.

I recommend using the two-statement solution.